# VERTICA: How to create a Loop

Tags: sql, loops, sas, vertica

I'm trying to create a loop in Vertica based off an example written in SAS.

How can I achieve this?

```
do i = 1 to 24;
    if 3 <= 24 - (intck('MONTH', &startdate, datepart(accountopeneddate))) - i + 1 <= 24 
        then stat[i] = status[24 - (intck('MONTH', &startdate, datepart(accountopeneddate))) - i + 1];
        else stat[i] = '';
end;
run;
```

Comment: Please show what research you've done so far and post any code you've written in your own attempt to solve this, even if it isn't working properly yet.

Comment: I know nothing about Vertica, but I would start by refactoring the SAS code so that the date calculation is only done once, outside the loop, without the repeat of `intck('MONTH', &startdate, datepart(accountopeneddate))`

Answer (score 1):

Vertica is a plain SQL database. SQL has no loops, which is often an advantage.
Also, SQL has no arrays, no variables, and no means to assign anything to anything.

You could at most create a table with as many rows as you would have array elements.

If your `status[]` array has 24 elements, you could go:

```
\set startdate '''2019-01-01'''                                                                                             

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS show;
CREATE TABLE show AS
WITH
status_tb(i,status) AS (
          SELECT   1,'unrevised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT   2,'1st revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT   3,'2nd revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT   4,'3rd revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT   5,'4th revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT   6,'5th revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT   7,'6th revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT   8,'7th revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT   9,'8th revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  10,'9th revised draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  11,'1st rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  12,'2nd rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  13,'3rd rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  14,'4th rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  15,'5th rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  16,'6th rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  17,'7th rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  18,'8th rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  19,'9th rejected draft'
UNION ALL SELECT  20,'1st approved version'
UNION ALL SELECT  21,'2rd approved version'
UNION ALL SELECT  22,'3th approved version'
UNION ALL SELECT  23,'4th approved version'
UNION ALL SELECT  24,'5th approved version'
)
,
account(accountopeneddate) AS (
SELECT '2019-08-15'::DATE
)
SELECT
    i.i
  , status
  , DATEDIFF(MONTH,:startdate,accountopeneddate) AS mth_btw
FROM account CROSS JOIN (SELECT i FROM status_tb) i
LEFT JOIN status_tb
  ON
    CASE
      WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,:startdate,accountopeneddate) - i.i + 1 BETWEEN 3 AND 24
      THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,:startdate,accountopeneddate) - i.i + 1
      ELSE NULL
    END = status_tb.i
;
SELECT * FROM show ORDER BY 1;
-- out DROP TABLE
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 7.469 ms. All rows formatted: 7.496 ms
-- out CREATE TABLE
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 81.812 ms. All rows formatted: 81.824 ms
-- out  i  |      status       | mth_btw 
-- out ----+-------------------+---------
-- out   1 | 6th revised draft |       7
-- out   2 | 5th revised draft |       7
-- out   3 | 4th revised draft |       7
-- out   4 | 3rd revised draft |       7
-- out   5 | 2nd revised draft |       7
-- out   6 |                   |       7
-- out   7 |                   |       7
-- out   8 |                   |       7
-- out   9 |                   |       7
-- out  10 |                   |       7
-- out  11 |                   |       7
-- out  12 |                   |       7
-- out  13 |                   |       7
-- out  14 |                   |       7
-- out  15 |                   |       7
-- out  16 |                   |       7
-- out  17 |                   |       7
-- out  18 |                   |       7
-- out  19 |                   |       7
-- out  20 |                   |       7
-- out  21 |                   |       7
-- out  22 |                   |       7
-- out  23 |                   |       7
-- out  24 |                   |       7
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Vertica SQL syntax.

Your two options are to create a UDx in the language of your choice ([Using User-Defined Extensions](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ExtendingVertica/UsingUserDefinedExtensions.htm)), or to have whatever application you have interfacing with Vertica take care of the logic for you.